# Asymmetric encryption using KMS public key outside AWS

Tags: amazon-kms

I am looking for a way to use the public key of an AWS KMS asymmetric key outside AWS for encryption.  The encrypted data could then be decrypted inside the AWS account using KMS.  I have found a way to use openssl to encrypt data outside using the KMS public key.  However, this only works for small amounts of data.

Is it possible to encrypt a large file using a KMS public key without access to AWS, and then use KMS to decrypt the file?

Comment: "public key" is a general notation for Private-/Public key cryptography. There are some cryptosystems with their own limitations. Using a RSA keypair limits you to a plaintext of (keysize in byte) - some bytes (11-~60) are reserved for padding use. A possible way could be "ECIES" encryption with an elliptic keypair - there are no real limits regarding plaintext size as (internally) an one-time-key is generated and used for AES encryption. This random AES key gets encrypted by the EC encryption. I don't know if AWS provides these keys and encryption schemes.

Comment: According to the AWS documentation, this is what is supported:
AWS KMS supports the RSAES_OAEP_SHA_1 and RSAES_OAEP_SHA_256 encryption algorithms with RSA 2048, RSA 3072, and RSA 4096 key types. Encryption algorithms cannot be used with the elliptic curve key types (ECC NIST P-256, ECC NIST P-384, ECC NIST-521, and ECC SECG P-256k1).